# php multiple headers

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm using a header to show succes message after submit. I also want to redirect the user to the index.php page after 5 seconds, but somehow it doesn't work.

```
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    header("Location: addbusiness.php?message=<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert' style='text-align: center; margin-bottom: 50px;'>Succes.</div>");
    header( "refresh:5;url=index.php" );
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Comment: second header with `refresh` has to be placed into `addbusiness.php` page actually. also there is no reason to send ***entire*** HTML message, just send an ID or some other param and display corresponding message, based on that into your next page.

Comment: If i place it into adbusiness.php it will refresh every time I'm using that page. I don't want that.

Comment: you could use the same condition when to display a message, to do `refresh`, see below..

Comment: Please read [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply can't do `location` and `refresh` at the same time, so you have to separate both headers, i.e. the `refresh` should be part of the page where you are displaying the message. Also, there is no reason (it's a bad practice actually) to pass entire HTML into the URL, better use some ID, like:

**db.php**

```
<?php
    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
        header("Location: addbusiness.php?message=1");
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
?>
```

**addbusiness.php**

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_GET['message'])){
        if($_GET['message'] == 1){
            header( "refresh:5;url=index.php" );
            echo "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert' style='text-align: center; margin-bottom: 50px;'>Success.</div>";
        }else{
            //do something else
        }
    }
?>
```

Based on such a condition, you also will avoid the refresh every time when visits `addbusiness.php`

Of course, in any case you have to ensure that there is no any HTML output to the browser before calling `header()`. In both pages.

Comment: Thank you for your clearly understandable answer. I'll use this id stuff, but there isn't any way to display a message and after that refresh the page? Because it's not an option for me to refresh it every time.

Comment: the script will do exactly that - will display the message and after that will do a rafresh. And will do it ONLY if you call `addbusiness.php` with `GET` parameter `message=1` otherwhise, the page will be loaded normally.

Comment: I get this error message: ```Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\vallalkozok-v2\addbusiness.php:1) in C:\xampp\htdocs\vallalkozok-v2\addbusiness.php on line 112``` but there isn't any php code in the first line.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, this code must be placed before any HTML output, best on the top of the page.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Now it's working fine. Thanks for your help. Accepted your answer.